# Multiple vars inside Jquery .val() - Multi select update

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What i want:**

I want to update a Multiple option  with the current user permissions
if i do it manually on jquery, it works:

```
$('#edit-input-perm').val(['A','B','C']).trigger('change');
```

on the same jquery i have an ajax call to fech me data from my database:

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'api/admin/crud/crud-fetch-user.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: "json",
          data : {id:id, func:func},
          success :  function(response){
```

My **crud-fetch-user.php** fetch and return:

```
< MYSQL connection here >

$permString = "[".($perm['permZad'] == 1 ? '\'zad\',': '').($perm['permZof'] == 1 ? '\'zof\',': '').($perm['permZfr'] == 1 ? '\'zfr\',': '').($perm['permZau'] == 1 ? '\'zau\',': '').($perm['permZco'] == 1 ? '\'zco\',': '').($perm['permZte'] == 1 ? '\'zte\',': '').($perm['permClt'] == 1 ? '\'clt\',': '');
        $permList=rtrim($permString ,", "); // removes the last ,
        $permList = $permList."]";

        $retorno = array('codigo' => 1, 'id' => $id, 'u' => $username, 'as' => $accountStatus, 'aim' => $avatarImg, 'na' => $name, 'em' => $email, 'ph' => $phone, 'isc' => $isClient, 'frcmp' => $fromCompany, 'frfil' => $fromFilial, 'rol' => $role, 'permList' => $permList);
        echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Json returns 'permList' => $permList

permList contains ['perm1','perm2','perm3','perm4'] if the values are 1 on the fetch.

So far so good.

**Now back to my Jquery code:**

response.permList now contains ['perm1','perm2','perm3','perm4']

and i need to put it inside of

$('#edit-input-perm').val(**HERE**).trigger('change');

Comment: It's a bit confusing to understand your question because I have the feeling you are mixing PHP and JavaScript code. Can you please make that separation clear in your question? Also, knowing what your HTML is would help.

Comment: `var zad = response.zad; ...` why a variable for each property of the response instead of just using `response.zad` directly?

Comment: @DanielBeck because the array is how you set a multiple select's value in jQuery...

Comment: My guess is the array method you are returning is not an array, but a  string.  Hard to tell since we have no clue how you are spitting out the response.

Comment: I guess that's my problem. My ajax call returns json and i was storing it in a var in js, not in array . so i guess it's storing it as a string, right? @epascarello

Comment: " i was storing it in a var in js, not in array" That makes no sense... No the issue would be you are returning a string and not an array. Again, I can not tell what is happening since I see no code.

Comment: @epascarello i've updated the main question with the code. sorry that my code it's far from perfect :) i'm always trying to learn

Comment: @epascarello you are right . the problem was that the method inside val was not in array format. Thanks for the help! i Got it to work by creating an empty array and pushing values to it from the json response. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188848/discussion-between-artur-mendes-and-epascarello).

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want all the keys that are one, than filter would work.

```
var values = Object.keys(response)
  .filter(key => response[key] === 1)
```

or

```
var values = Object.keys(response)
  .filter(function (key) { return response[key] === 1; })

$('#edit-input-perm').val(values).trigger('change');
```